# What are some real-life use-cases of issubclass()?

Tags: python, class, class-hierarchy

I've been looking for it for quite some time, googling different phrases, but I can't find any real-life use-cases of `issubclass()` in Python.

I mean, I understand how it works. For example:

```py
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

issubclass(B, A)  # returns True
```

However, I don't know how I can use it in a program. Is there a simple use-case? For example, you can use `isinstance()` in the implementation of your `__eq__()` method and that's a clear and understandable example.

I'm looking for something similar and straight-forward in usage. I can imagine a more complicated program, where a class is passed for instantiation and `issubclass()` is used to determine which constructor I should choose. Unfortunately, this problem feels more artificial and is neither simple nor real-life. Every time a problem comes to my mind, it's solved by `isinstance()` not `issublcass()`...

Comment: Consider that``issubclass`` means reasoning about types themselves *without values*. A "simple use-case" is most likely ruled out just by the definition of the problem alone.

Comment: The Python stdlib has lots of real-life examples of `issubclass` usage. Most site-packages directories will also have a huge number of further examples (e.g. from numpy, pandas, sqlalchemy, etc).